# Setting a particular object for a section of HTML with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

*Apologies if this is a duplicate -- this is a hard question to search for because it's about very common functionality, but doesn't have any distinctive keywords...*

I know how to use **ng-repeat** to obtain objects one by one, eg:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.name}} {{person.address}}</li>
```

But what if I want to specify a particular object? I mean something like: ***(I realize this is not correct Angular)***

```
<h1>Project Directors' Contact Info</h1>
<li>{{personWithName('Jonah').name}} {{personWithName('Jonah').address}}</li>
<li>{{personWithName('Ann').name}} {{personWithName('Ann').address}}</li>
```

or maybe

```
<h1>Project Directors' Contact Info</h1>
<li ng-model="{person = personWithName('Jonah')}">{{person.name}} {{person.address}}</li>
<li ng-model="{person = personWithName('Ann')}">{{person.name}} {{person.address}}</li>
```

Assuming I have some function in the controller's scope that makes it easy to grab the particular object/record I want, what's the right syntax for creating a sort of variable in the angular view markup so i'm not just calling that grab/find function over and over?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?  May be an example of your expected output would help explain your needs further.  It does look like ng-show will provide an option for what you want to do

Comment: I want to display fields of an object, without repeatedly redefining that object redundantly; I want to produce view code that is abstracting away the controller logic as much as possible; I want to learn what experienced angular developers would do in this case.

Comment: Do you mean like <li ng-show="name='Jonah'"> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be to create a custom directive, so I can do:

```
<ng-bw-person name="Jonah">
<ng-bw-person name="Anne">
```

Best explanation I've seen of this is in the Angular in 50 examples talk, part 2. I highly recommend the whole thing.

Though admittedly, a custom directive seems like overkill in the case of just a single instance or two... Still feel like there's a better way!

Answer (score 2):

Your example -

```
<h1>Project Directors' Contact Info</h1>
<li>{{personWithName('Jonah').name}} {{personWithName('Jonah').address}}</li>
<li>{{personWithName('Ann').name}} {{personWithName('Ann').address}}</li>
```

Would work if you define $scope.personWithName in your controller as a function that grabs a particular object from a collection by it's name property.

Comment: Thanks, but if i have dozens of places per line that i want to access fields like name and address, it doesn't make much sense to call this function again and again, does it?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking to achieve - perhaps using an ng-repeat with an angular filter to control which objects are actually displayed?  Really the solution depends on what you want to display and how you want to display it. It's hard to imagine what "dozens of places per line" really means without more context.

Comment: I think the problem is that what I'm imagining would actually violate MVC separation. I want to have the model grab the person with name "Jonah" once, then reuse that variable in its displaying of different fields. But the model doesn't have a linear execution like controller code does. I guess just repeatedly doing personWithName('Jonah') is the way to do it -- the controller could just cache the record in a local variable if fetching is costly (eg if fetching must be done across http)

Comment: Repeatedly calling the same function violates DRY. And ng-repeat for a set of exactly one object seems hacky.